# Set disable attribute based on a condition for Html.TextBoxFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html-helper

I want to set disable attribute based on a condition for Html.TextBoxFor in asp.net MVC like below

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ExpireDate, new { style = "width: 70px;", maxlength = "10", id = "expire-date" disabled = (Model.ExpireDate == null ? "disable" : "") })
```

This helper has two output disabled="disabled " or disabled="". both of theme make the textbox disable.

I want to disable the textbox if Model.ExpireDate == null else I want to enable it

Comment: Have a look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43131930/6680521

Answer (score 91, accepted):

The valid way is:

```
disabled="disabled"
```

Browsers also might *accept* `disabled=""` but I would recommend you the first approach.

Now this being said I would recommend you writing a custom HTML helper in order to encapsulate this *disabling* functionality into a reusable piece of code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;
using System.Web.Routing;

public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString MyTextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(
        this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, 
        Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, 
        object htmlAttributes, 
        bool disabled
    )
    {
        var attributes = new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes);
        if (disabled)
        {
            attributes["disabled"] = "disabled";
        }
        return htmlHelper.TextBoxFor(expression, attributes);
    }
}
```

which you could use like this:

```
@Html.MyTextBoxFor(
    model => model.ExpireDate, 
    new { 
        style = "width: 70px;", 
        maxlength = "10", 
        id = "expire-date" 
    }, 
    Model.ExpireDate == null
)
```

---

and you could bring even more *intelligence* into this helper:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString MyTextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(
        this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
        Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression,
        object htmlAttributes
    )
    {
        var attributes = new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes);
        var metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
        if (metaData.Model == null)
        {
            attributes["disabled"] = "disabled";
        }
        return htmlHelper.TextBoxFor(expression, attributes);
    }
}
```

so that now you no longer need to specify the disabled condition:

```
@Html.MyTextBoxFor(
    model => model.ExpireDate, 
    new { 
        style = "width: 70px;", 
        maxlength = "10", 
        id = "expire-date" 
    }
)
```

Comment: I want to disable the textbox if Model.ExpireDate == null else I want to enable it

Comment: This solution is great - as far as it goes... but it would be nice to find a clean solution that doesn't require putting a wrapper around every HtmlHelper we use that might have a disabled attribute (TextBoxFor, TextAreaFor, CheckBoxFor, etc.) Ideally something that works inline with the existing ones. I've built a solution that basically just wraps the anonymous object and returns a RouteValueDictionary - but it doesn't feel especially clean.

Comment: "disabled", "disabled=''" and "disabled='disabled'" are all equally valid in html, and it is misleading (and false) to say that the shorter ones might only be *accepted* by the different browsers. Cf. http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/syntax.html#syntax-attr-empty

Answer (score 58):

Actually, the internal behavior is translating the anonymous object to a dictionary.
So what I do in these scenarios is go for a dictionary:

```
@{
  var htmlAttributes = new Dictionary<string, object>
  {
    { "class" , "form-control"},
    { "placeholder", "Why?" }        
  };
  if (Model.IsDisabled)
  {
    htmlAttributes.Add("disabled", "disabled");
  }
}
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Description, new { htmlAttributes = htmlAttributes })
```

Or, as Stephen commented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29247726/how-do-i-conditionally-specify-whether-html-input-is-disabled-readonly-or-not/29247861?noredirect=1#comment46700636_29247726):

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Description,
    Model.IsDisabled ? (object)new { disabled = "disabled" } : (object)new { })
```

Comment: @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Description,
    Model.IsDisabled ? (object)new { disabled = "disabled" } : (object)new { }) => this seems the best way. Thanks

Answer (score 23):

I like Darin method. But quick way to solve this,

```
Html.TextBox("Expiry", null, new { style = "width: 70px;", maxlength = "10", id = "expire-date", disabled = "disabled" }).ToString().Replace("disabled=\"disabled\"", (1 == 2 ? "" : "disabled=\"disabled\""))
```

Comment: I think you should surround this with @Html.Raw()

Answer (score 18):

One simple approach I have used is conditional rendering:

```
@(Model.ExpireDate == null ? 
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ExpireDate, new { @disabled = "disabled" }) : 
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ExpireDate)
)
```

Answer (score 16):

If you don't use html helpers you may use simple ternary expression like this:

```
<input name="Field"
       value="@Model.Field" tabindex="0"
       @(Model.IsDisabledField ? "disabled=\"disabled\"" : "")>
```

Answer (score 13):

I achieved it using some extension methods

```
private const string endFieldPattern = "^(.*?)>";

    public static MvcHtmlString IsDisabled(this MvcHtmlString htmlString, bool disabled)
    {
        string rawString = htmlString.ToString();
        if (disabled)
        {
            rawString = Regex.Replace(rawString, endFieldPattern, "$1 disabled=\"disabled\">");
        }

        return new MvcHtmlString(rawString);
    }

    public static MvcHtmlString IsReadonly(this MvcHtmlString htmlString, bool @readonly)
    {
        string rawString = htmlString.ToString();
        if (@readonly)
        {
            rawString = Regex.Replace(rawString, endFieldPattern, "$1 readonly=\"readonly\">");
        }

        return new MvcHtmlString(rawString);
    }
```

and then....

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { @class= "someclass"}).IsDisabled(Model.ExpireDate == null)
```

Comment: Works if you change rawstring.Length - 2 for 7 and add " " after last ".

Comment: Doesn't work with TextAreaFor, need a solution for all kind of input types

Answer (score 11):

Is solved this using RouteValueDictionary (works fine as htmlAttributes as it's based on IDictionary) and an extension method:

```
public static RouteValueDictionary AddIf(this RouteValueDictionary dict, bool condition, string name, object value)
{
    if (condition) dict.Add(name, value);
    return dict;
}
```

Usage:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.GovId, new RouteValueDictionary(new { @class = "form-control" })
.AddIf(Model.IsEntityFieldsLocked, "disabled", "disabled"))
```

Credit goes to https://stackoverflow.com/a/3481969/40939

Comment: IMHO, this is the best answer

Answer (score 10):

This is late, but may be helpful to some people.

I have extended @DarinDimitrov's answer to allow for passing a second object that takes any number of boolean html attributes like `disabled="disabled" checked="checked", selected="selected"` etc.

It will render the attribute only if the property value is true, anything else and the attribute will not be rendered at all.

The custom reuseble HtmlHelper:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString MyTextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
                                                                Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression,
                                                                object htmlAttributes,
                                                                object booleanHtmlAttributes)
    {
        var attributes = new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes);

        //Reflect over the properties of the newly added booleanHtmlAttributes object
        foreach (var prop in booleanHtmlAttributes.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            //Find only the properties that are true and inject into the main attributes.
            //and discard the rest.
            if (ValueIsTrue(prop.GetValue(booleanHtmlAttributes, null)))
            {
                attributes[prop.Name] = prop.Name;
            }                
        }                                

        return htmlHelper.TextBoxFor(expression, attributes);
    }

    private static bool ValueIsTrue(object obj)
    {
        bool res = false;
        try
        {
            res = Convert.ToBoolean(obj);
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            res = false;
        }
        catch(InvalidCastException)
        {
            res = false;
        }
        return res;
    }

}
```

Which you can use like so:

```
@Html.MyTextBoxFor(m => Model.Employee.Name
                   , new { @class = "x-large" , placeholder = "Type something…" }
                   , new { disabled = true})
```

Answer (score 7):

if you dont want to use Html Helpers
take look it my solution

```
disabled="@(your Expression that returns true or false")"
```

that it

```
@{
    bool isManager = (Session["User"] as User).IsManager;
}
<textarea rows="4" name="LetterManagerNotes" disabled="@(!isManager)"></textarea>
```

and I think the better way to do it is to do that check in the controller and save it within a variable that is accessible inside the view(Razor engine) in order to make `the view free from business logic`

Comment: If you use the disabled attribute in a control, the control will be disabled no matter what value the attribute has. Even the presence of the attribute without a value will disable the control.

Comment: This solution works really well, and I suspect downvoters may have overlooked that the expression is boolean. When the expression is boolean, the disabled attribute will render as disabled="disabled" if the expression is true, or be completely omitted if false. Which is exactly what you want.

Comment: This will either render disabled="false" or disabled="true", no?

Answer (score 4):

Yet another solution would be to create a `Dictionary<string, object>` before calling `TextBoxFor` and pass that dictionary. In the dictionary, add `"disabled"` key only if the textbox is to be diabled. Not the neatest solution but simple and straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to disable the text box on the client side.

In your case you have only one textbox that you need to disable but consider the case where you have multiple input, select, and textarea fields that yout need to disable.

It is much easier to do it via jquery + (since we can not rely on data coming from the client) add some logic to the controller to prevent these fields from being saved.

Here is an example:

```
<input id="document_Status" name="document.Status" type="hidden" value="2" />

$(document).ready(function () {

    disableAll();
}

function disableAll() {
  var status = $('#document_Status').val();

  if (status != 0) {
      $("input").attr('disabled', true);
      $("textarea").attr('disabled', true);
      $("select").attr('disabled', true);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I like the extension method approach so you don't have to pass through all possible parameters.
However using Regular expressions can be quite tricky (and somewhat slower) so I used `XDocument` instead:

```cs
public static MvcHtmlString SetDisabled(this MvcHtmlString html, bool isDisabled)
{
    var xDocument = XDocument.Parse(html.ToHtmlString());
    if (!(xDocument.FirstNode is XElement element))
    {
        return html;
    }

    element.SetAttributeValue("disabled", isDisabled ? "disabled" : null);
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(element.ToString());
}
```

Use the extension method like this:
`@Html.EditorFor(m => m.MyProperty).SetDisabled(Model.ExpireDate == null)`

Answer (score 0):

The extension below is very simple and straight forward. It gets the resulting HTML string returned by the helper and adds the *disabled* attribute if true.

```
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;
using System.Web.Mvc;   

namespace MyApplication.Extensions
{
    public static class MyExtensions
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString Locked(this MvcHtmlString htmlString, bool lockThis)
        {
            string html = htmlString.ToString();
            return new MvcHtmlString(lockThis ? html.Replace("id=", " disabled id=") : html );
        }
    }
}
```

This approach will work for all Html editing helpers and not just the **HtmlTextBoxFor**. Simply add **.Locked(bool)** to your fields and set the boolean condition at the top of your view as shown below.

Example:

```
@using MyApplication.Extensions
@model MyModel

@{
    // Set condition to true if not an Admin or Manager
    bool lockCondition = (!User.IsInRole("Admin") && !User.IsInRole("Manager"));
}
.
.
<div class="col-md-6">
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CommisionAmt).Locked(lockCondition)
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?