# How do I conditionally specify whether HTML input is disabled/readonly OR NOT?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, disabled-input

Here's a sample of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Description, 
  new { htmlAttributes = 
    new 
    {
      @class = "form-control",
      @readonly = Model.IsReadOnly,
      disabled = Model.IsDisabled
    }
  })
```

The problem is that the browser treats the existence of the `readonly` and `disabled` tokens without checking for their content, so when the `IsReadOnly` and `IsDisabled` properties are `false`, it will still show as `disabled`.

Is there any simple solution for that?

Comment: Maybe you should write [your own extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6660146/set-disable-attribute-based-on-a-condition-for-html-textboxfor) for this.

Comment: You would need to test each condition - e.g. `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Description, Model.IsDisabled ? (object)new { disabled = "disabled" } : (object)new { })`

Comment: @StephenMuecke by far the most convenient answer. Why not write a proper answer?

Comment: @Shimmy, Just showing what you could do, but its going to be rather long and messy because you have 2 conditions to check (`Model.IsReadOnly` and `Model.IsDisabled`). If this is not a 'once off' I would consider a custom helper (and do you really want to disable controls? - they wont post back).

Comment: @StephenMuecke, just included them for the sake of the example. Anyway, I've found an elegant solution and posted it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29248004/75500), since this question is closed as a dupe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML :-

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Description, 
  new { htmlAttributes = 
    new 
    {
      @class = "form-control"
    }
});
```

Try using jQuery as shown :-

```
if(@Json.Encode(Model.IsReadOnly))
{
   $('#Description').attr('readonly','readonly')
}

if(@Json.Encode(Model.IsDisabled))
{
   $('#Description').attr('disabled','disabled')
}
```