# How to make a boolean HTML5 attribute 'conditional' in ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html, razor

I'm using ASP.Net MVC (5.2.3.0) to create a form field:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(
    x => x.UserName, 
    new { 
        @class = "form-control", 
        placeholder = "Enter your username", 
        required = true, 
        autofocus = true 
});
```

So far so good, but now I like to make the `autofocus` attribute **conditional**. How would I go about?

The `autofocus` attribute is a boolean attribute and [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#boolean-attribute) states:

> Note: The values "true" and "false" are not allowed on boolean
>   attributes. To represent a false value, the attribute has to be
>   omitted altogether.

The following doesn't work in MVC, because it still renders the `autofocus` attribute causing the browser to do the auto focus:

```
autofocus = String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Model.UserName)
autofocus = String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Model.UserName) ? null : ""`
```

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Comment: That's true, in practice all browsers ignore the value. How would I go about in getting the TextBoxFor _not_ to render the attribute.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set disable attribute based on a condition for Html.TextBoxFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6660146/set-disable-attribute-based-on-a-condition-for-html-textboxfor)

Comment: As a side note, the `required` attribute is also a `boolean` attribute

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create an attribute dictionary somewhere before in the view:

```
@{
    var usernameAttrs = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        {"class ", "form-control"},
        {"placeholder  ", "Enter your username"},
        {"required", true},
    };

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Model.UserName))
    {
        usernameAttrs.Add("autofocus", true);
    }
}
```

and use it in the `TextBoxFor()`

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.UserName, usernameAttrs);
```

Comment: This works. But the if condition needs to be between `{ }`, otherwise compilations fails.

Answer (score 0):

check your condition in controller and if true set `ViewBag.Tag = autofocus` and then in your view

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(
    x => x.UserName, 
    new { 
        @class = "form-control", 
        placeholder = "Enter your username", 
        required = true, 
        ViewBag.Tag 
});
```

Comment: I don't understand this solution. Can you elaborate?

Comment: in your controller if ( !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.UserName)){ViewBag.Tag="autofocus"}  and then you have ViewBag.tag in your view if the condition is not true then it just do nothing and if it is true it just print add autofocus as attribute.

Comment: ViewBag is Dynamic Type in C# , so you can add properties to it in runtime as we did in above example.

Comment: But I have a form with multiple fields. How would I go about in such a case?

Comment: excuse me but i am not clear about your comment , you can use autofocus only for one form field  .

Comment: True, but when I have a condition, I can choose which field I would like to focus.

Comment: what is your condition ?

Comment: If field A is empty, I focus the control for field A else if B is empty, I focus the control for field B else I focus a submit button control.

Comment: well here you have two option , first you can use Linus Caldwell approach as he explained above , using dictionary type and using your if condition in your view , second option witch i think is a bit messy is to add another properties to your ViewBag and set its value as name of your class properties and in your view check that. for example  if (yourobject.fieldA!=null){ViewBag.PropertyName="fieldA",ViewBag.tag=autofocus} and now check ViewBag.PropertyName .