# How to disable property of model with the attribute in C#?

Tags: c#, html, .net, razor

Screenshots:

- [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbZle.png)
- [ui result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6xhE.png)

I want disable email field but `[Editable(false)]` attribute does not work.

How can I solve this problem?

```
[NopResourceDisplayName("Admin.Address.Fields.Email")]
[AllowHtml]
//[Editable(false)]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

`ReadOnly(true)` attribute also does not work.

Comment: Do not post image of your code... paste as text, so that it is easily viewed & searched.

Comment: See the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/29248004/14973743

Comment: It looks like there are red underlines in your code,`@Html.EditFor()`,you need to check if you have missed something.And when using `@Html.EditFor()`,`readonly` will not work,you need to use `@Html.TextBoxFor` as `harrysrangal` said.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your HTML Helper method from EditorFor to TetBoxFor. Something line this.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email, new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" })
```