# Converting class properties to key-value pair

Tags: c#, key-value

I have these two classes

```
public class BuyEstimateResult
{
    public string SubTitle { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Formulae { get; set; }
}
public class SellerReportClass
{
    public string Entityname { get; set; }
    public double EntityAmt { get; set; }
    public string Formulae { get; set; }
}
```

I have to make them such that it should be converted as

```
public class KeyValue
{
    public string key {get;set;}
    public string value {get;set;}
}
```

if I pass BuyEstimateResult, its SubTitle should be key and Value should be Value of KeyValue Class and if I pass SellerReportClass then Entityname sould be key and EntityAmt should be Value

any ideas how can it be done

NOTE: I will get List of Both the class

Comment: which method you want to pass list of both objects? pls could you post the code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert object to Dictionary<TKey, TValue> in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11576886/how-to-convert-object-to-dictionarytkey-tvalue-in-c)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `implicit` operator in C# to convert it into a `KeyValue` like you want - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2(v=vs.110).aspx

```
public static implicit operator KeyValue(BuyEstimateResult ber)
{
     return new KeyValue { Key = ber.SubTitle, Value = ber.Value }
}
```

**Edit**

To be more specific on how to implement this:

```
public class BuyEstimateResult
{
    public string SubTitle { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Formulae { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator KeyValue(BuyEstimateResult ber)
    {
        return new KeyValue {Key = ber.SubTitle, Value = ber.Value};
    }
}

public class SellerReportClass
{
    public string Entityname { get; set; }
    public double EntityAmt { get; set; }
    public string Formulae { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator KeyValue(SellerReportClass sell)
    {
        return new KeyValue { Key = sell.Entityname, Value = sell.EntityAmt.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)};
    }
}

public class KeyValue
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var listB = new List<BuyEstimateResult>
                        {
                            new BuyEstimateResult {SubTitle = "BER1", Value = "BER1_VALUE"},
                            new BuyEstimateResult {SubTitle = "BER2", Value = "BER2_VALUE"}
                        };

        var listS = new List<SellerReportClass>
                        {
                            new SellerReportClass {Entityname = "SELL1", EntityAmt = 1.0},
                            new SellerReportClass {Entityname = "SELL2", EntityAmt = 2.5}
                        };

        foreach (KeyValue kv in listB)
            Console.WriteLine(kv.Key + ":" + kv.Value);

        foreach (KeyValue kv in listS)
            Console.WriteLine(kv.Key + ":" + kv.Value);
    }
}
```

To get a single list of `KeyValue` objects from the two different lists you can do something like this:

```
var KeyValueList = listB.ConvertAll(i => (KeyValue) i);
KeyValueList.AddRange(listS.ConvertAll(i => (KeyValue) i));
```

Comment: Cool stuff, never saw it before

Comment: how does it work, please explain more along with usage, i guess this handles single object, how about list??

Comment: Amazing stuff, this is what i was looking for

Comment: What about Formulae  property? why it was ignored? Crappy answer.