# Converting dynamic type to dictionary C#

Tags: c#, json, dynamic, dictionary, json.net

I have a dynamic object that looks like this,

```
 {
    "2" : "foo",
    "5" : "bar",
    "8" : "foobar"
 }
```

How can I convert this to a `dictionary`?

Comment: This looks like JSON. Are you looking for JSON *deserialization* into a `Dictionary<K,V>`?

Comment: You can use Linq Group method. Look here: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-to-DataSets-Grouping-c62703ea

Comment: what object is it? JSON string? or JSON object? or List of KeyValuePair? or something else??

Comment: @OndrejTucny Actually this is a product of a JSON deserilization. Done like this: Dictionary<string, dynamic> values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(json) The "json" in the question is the value that was stuffed into my dictionary

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can use a [`RouteValueDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routevaluedictionary.aspx) to convert a C# object to a dictionary. See: [RouteValueDictionary Class - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routevaluedictionary.aspx). It converts `object` properties to key-value pairs.

Use it like this:

```c#
var toBeConverted = new {
    foo = 2,
    bar = 5,
    foobar = 8
};

var result = new RouteValueDictionary(toBeConverted);
```

Comment: clever way of repurposing an existing class!

Answer (score 52):

You can fill the dictionary using reflection:

```
public Dictionary<String, Object> Dyn2Dict(dynamic dynObj)
{
     var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
     foreach (PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(dynObj))
     {
        object obj = propertyDescriptor.GetValue(dynObj);
        dictionary.Add(propertyDescriptor.Name, obj);
     }
     return dictionary;
}
```

Comment: As it's not marked as the best answer. I think this should be upper. This gives a lot more possibility to devs in general

Comment: Does not work if dynamic object is ExpandoObject

Answer (score 23):

If the dynamic value in question was created via deserialization from Json.Net as you mentioned in your comments, then it should be a [`JObject`](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm).  It turns out that `JObject` already implements `IDictionary<string, JToken>`, so you can use it as a dictionary without any conversion, as shown below:

```
string json = 
     @"{ ""blah"" : { ""2"" : ""foo"", ""5"" : ""bar"", ""8"" : ""foobar"" } }";

var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(json);
dynamic dyn = dict["blah"];

Console.WriteLine(dyn.GetType().FullName);     // Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject
Console.WriteLine(dyn["2"].ToString());        // foo
```

If you would rather have a `Dictionary<string, string>` instead, you can convert it like this:

```
Dictionary<string, string> newDict = 
          ((IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, JToken>>)dyn)
                     .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value.ToString());
```

Answer (score 14):

You can use [Json.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html) to deserialize it to dictionary.

```
string json = dynamicObject.ToString(); // suppose `dynamicObject` is your input
Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);
```

Comment: Okay but `string json = dynamicObject.ToString()` didn't work out. You need `string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dynamicObject);`

Answer (score 4):

Very similar to ema answer, but with a one-liner using LINQ magic:

```
Dictionary<string, object> myDict = sourceObject.GetType().GetProperties().ToDictionary(prop => prop.Name, prop => prop.GetValue(sourceObject, null));
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way is using System.Web.Helpers.Json included in .NET 4.5.

Json.Encode(object) and Json.Decode. Like:

```
Json.Decode<Generic.Dictionary<string, string>>(value);
```

MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg547931(v=vs.111).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1

Regards,
MarianoC.

Comment: `System.Web.Helpers` is not included in .NET 4.5.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with jsonSerializer. And it requires System.Net.Extensions reference. Here is a sample code.

```
var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var dict = jss.Deserialize<Dictionary<string,string>>(jsonText);
var place = dict["8"]; // "foobar"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `dynamic` implementation here:

https://github.com/b9chris/GracefulDynamicDictionary

You can get the Dictionary right from the implementation. One advantage to using the above implementation (written for an answer to [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24192518/176877)), is you can shift easily between the specific implementation and dynamic, like so:

```
    dynamic headers = new DDict();
    headers.Authorization = token;
    if (doesNeedSiteId)
        headers.SiteId = siteId;
    
    await post(headers);
}

protected async Task post(DDict headers)
{
    var dict = headers.GetDictionary(); // Dictionary<string, object>
```

In the above, the headers collection is conveniently created as a `dynamic`, but, the underlying specific implementation is `DDict`, and the `post()` method accepts it even though you've declared it as `dynamic` and used its features.

Answer (score 0):

One line solution to convert your JSON text to Dictionary:

```
IDictionary<string, object> dict = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<IDictionary<string, object>>(json);
```

Then

```
if (dict.ContainsKey("field1"))
   string field1value = dict["field1"];
```