# Convert unknown KeyValuePair object to KeyValuePair<object, object>

Tags: c#, generics, casting, converters, keyvaluepair

I have an object that is of type `KeyValuePair<T1,T2>` , but the actual types of `T1,T2` are only known at run time. I would like to extract `Key` and `Value` of that object but I do not know how. Could you please help? (The idea is as below but it does not work)

```
public override IDictionary<string, object> Serialize(object obj, JavaScriptSerializer serializer) {
     KeyValuePair<object, object> kvp = (KeyValuePair<object, object>)obj;
     Console.WriteLine("[{0},{1}]", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11576886/how-to-convert-object-to-dictionarytkey-tvalue-in-c  ?

Comment: Thank you! I already thought of using reflection but I referred a possible way of casting/converting. I was a little worry about reflection performance (I have to convert a lot of these objects) but it seems the only way.

Comment: When the type is literally known by _none_ of the code at compile time, you're pretty much stuck with reflection or `dynamic`. E.g. "KeyValuePair<object, object> = new KeyValuePair<object, object>(((dynamic)obj).Key, ((dynamic)obj).Value)`. That said, these scenarios are unusual. It's likely there's a better approach in your particular scenario, but without more context it's not really possible to say in any specific way what that better approach would be.