# Convert any class to a keyvaluepair

Tags: c#, deserialization

I have a number (maybe a lot) of classes that are simple like so

```
 public class ResultA
    {
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public int Year { get; set; }
        public int Month { get; set; }
        public int Day { get; set; }
    }

 public class ResultB
    {
        public string Number { get; set; }
        public int Count { get; set; }
        public string Update { get; set; }
        public int Jewels{ get; set; }
    }
```

There is no common interface, but they don't have methods simply properties.

I would like to be able to convert any type like this into a `KeyValuePair<string,string>`  with the property name and the value if it is set.

Is there anyway of doing this horrible thing!?

Comment: Sounds like Reflection is your only way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert object to Dictionary<TKey, TValue> in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11576886/how-to-convert-object-to-dictionarytkey-tvalue-in-c)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use reflection like this:

```
[Test]
public void DoStuff() {
  List<object> things = new List<object>() {
    new ResultA(){Date = DateTime.Now, Month = 34}, new ResultB(){Count = 1, Jewels = 4, Number = "2", Update = "0"}
  };

  foreach (var thing in things) {
    foreach (var property in thing.GetType().GetProperties()) {
      Trace.WriteLine(property.Name + " " + property.GetValue(thing));
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Date 10.06.2015 13:46:41
Year 0
Month 34
Day 0
Number 2
Count 1
Update 0
Jewels 4
```

You can also use a extension method:

```
public static class ObjectExtensions {
  public static List<KeyValuePair<string, object>> GetProperties(this object me) {
    List<KeyValuePair<string, object>> result = new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>();
    foreach (var property in me.GetType().GetProperties()) {
      result.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>(property.Name, property.GetValue(me)));
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
  [Test]
  public void DoItWithExtensionMethod() {
    List<object> things = new List<object>() {
    new ResultA(){Date = DateTime.Now, Month = 34}, new ResultB(){Count = 1, Jewels = 4, Number = "2", Update = "0"}
    };

    foreach (var thing in things) {
      var properties = thing.GetProperties();
      foreach (var property in properties) {
        Trace.WriteLine(property.Key + " " + property.Value);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: If you love linq that code can go into 1 line: ```public static class ObjectExtensions
 {
  public static List<KeyValuePair<string, object>> GetProperties(this object me)
  {
   return me.GetType().GetProperties().Select(property => new KeyValuePair<string, object>(property.Name, property.GetValue(me))).ToList();
  }
 }```

Answer (score 20):

Peter beat me to it, but here is a quick linqpad:

```
void Main()
{
    GetValues(new ResultA
    {
        Date = DateTime.Now,
        Year = 2000
    }).Dump();
}

public IDictionary<string, string> GetValues(object obj) 
{
    return obj
            .GetType()
            .GetProperties()
            .ToDictionary(p=>p.Name, p=> p.GetValue(obj).ToString());
}

public class ResultA
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int Month { get; set; }
    public int Day { get; set; }
}
```

Output

```
Key   Value
Date  10-Jun-15 14:48:11 
Year  2000 
Month 0 
Day   0
```

Comment: LinqPad is a great tool! If this question helped you find that then it was well worth my time asking!