# I want to convert my LiNQ result to Dictionary

Tags: c#, linq

For example this is my query

```
var result = (from D in dbcontext.NPPES where D.NPI == item.NPI && D.ProviderFirstName == item.FirstName && D.ProviderLastName == item.LastName select new 
{
D.firstname,
D.lastname,
D.NPI
}).FirstOrDefault()
```

---

Now i want to pass my query result to function which iterates till last column converts the result into Dictionary result 
i want my result like this

```
dt["firstname"] = "john"
dt["lastname"] = "khan"
dt["NPI"]="123456"
```

What should i do in this case!
Plz Help

Comment: [ToDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549277(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: which version of c# are you using?

Comment: you can use mentioned helper that is in the answer of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11576886/how-to-convert-object-to-dictionarytkey-tvalue-in-c)

Comment: Since your result is typed you can simply write the code to do this using plain assignments. If however you need something generic I would use reflection.

Comment: @AshokRathod - That method requires that the object implement `IDictionary`. That's different from the OP's requirement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code:

```
var result = new { firstname = "Mary", lastname = "Poppins", NPI = "NPI" };

var dictionary =
    result
        .GetType()
        .GetProperties()
        .Where(x => x.PropertyType == typeof(string))
        .Select(x => new { x.Name, Value = (string)x.GetValue(result) })
        .ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x.Value);
```

I get:

[image: dictionary]