# How do I properly convert from a LINQ Result (as IEnumerable) to a delimited list without using reflection in .net?

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, ienumerable, anonymous-types

First of all, please forgive if I am way off on this as I am somewhat new to .net, anonymous types, and LINQ.  Frankly I'm struggling a bit and plan to do a lot of learning over the next month on the topic.  I know enough to know what I have come up with is not the right way.

I've been given a project to create various delimited output formats deriving from a standard report feed that has been in existence for some time.  There is already a framework in place for this and I am simply adding more formats and a few new output mechanisms.  (Some of the details that follow are likely irrelevant, but in the interest of clarity I will include.)

A query from the data tier returns an LLBLGEN TypedList.  A LINQ query is then applied to create the various feed output formats resulting in an IEnumerable anonymous object.  As part of my project I am then to take that object and output it as a comma delimited file.

By reviewing the examples below and some others I've been able to kludge together a working function, but I am certain that it is in no way the right way to accomplish the task (uses reflection, etc.).  That said, the "right way" eludes me!  Even a pointer in the right direction would be quite helpful.

[In c# convert anonymous type into key/value array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481923/in-c-sharp-convert-anonymous-type-into-key-value-array)

[A dictionary where value is an anonymous type in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619518/a-dictionary-where-value-is-an-anonymous-type-in-c-sharp)

```
Private Sub SendExport(feed As IEnumerable, filename As String)

    Dim delimited As New StringBuilder

    Dim type = feed(0).GetType
    Dim props = type.GetProperties
    delimited.AppendLine(String.Join(",", props.Select(Function(p) p.Name).ToList))

    For Each item In feed
        Dim itemType = item.GetType
        Dim typeProps = itemType.GetProperties
        delimited.AppendLine(String.Join(",", typeProps.Select(Function(p) p.GetValue(item)).ToList))
    Next

    Debug.WriteLine(delimited.ToString)

    Response.Clear()

    Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate")
    Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "must-revalidate")
    Response.AddHeader("Content-type", "application/vnd.ms-excel")
    Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", String.Format("attachment; filename={0}.csv", filename))
    Response.Write(delimited.ToString)
    Response.End()

End Sub
```

Comment: You could use a `DataTable` instead. Then you don't need to use reflection.

Comment: Is there an easy way to get from anonymous type or linq query result to a datatable?

Comment: You should not pass an anonymous type outside of the scope of a method, use it directly or use another type from the beginning. What kind of Linq query is it, Linq-To-Sql? Note that you also can use `Linq-To-DataTable` if the data is already in memory (f.e. via `DataAdapter.Fill(DataTable)`). You could also use a custom base class for all your other classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is quite old, but in the interest of potentially helping the next person I thought I'd provide the answer I eventually came to in my own learning and research.

In short and quite simply, Tim Schmelter had it right in his comment to my original request:

> You should not pass an anonymous type outside of the scope of a
>   method, use it directly or use another type from the beginning.

What I was attempting to accomplish was fundamentally incorrect from a design perspective and basically a misuse of the anonymous type.  The correct "answer" in my case was to simply refactor the reporting tier to use strongly-typed classes across the board.  LINQ queries populate the classes directly, etc.  Was a relatively small effort and made things much cleaner in the end.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert in VB, but I think you can remove the following lines out of the loop:

```
Dim itemType = item.GetType
Dim typeProps = itemType.GetProperties
```

And simply reuse the `props` list again:

```
For Each item In feed
    delimited.AppendLine(String.Join(",", props.Select(Function(p) p.GetValue(item)).ToList))
Next
```