# Converting an anonymous type to a dictionary

Tags: c#, reflection

I am attempting to create a function that converts an anonymous type to a dictionary.
I was going over the accepted answer in this link [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481923/in-c-sharp-convert-anonymous-type-into-key-value-array). However I am getting the error

> Cannot use lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically
>   dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or
>   expression tree type

This is what I am trying to do

```
public Dictionary<string,string> convert(dynamic dtype)
{
 var props = content.GetType().GetProperties();
 var pairs = props.Select(x => x.Name + "=" + x.GetValue(a, null)).ToArray();  // <----Exception
 var result = string.Join("&", pairs);
 return result
}
```

Any suggestion on how I can fix this ? I am trying to do this

```
       var student= new
        {
            // TODO: Make this figure out and return underlying device status.
            type = "Active",
        };



 var dict = convert(student);
```

Comment: Change the parameter type from `dynamic` to `object`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

exception is here :

```
 x.GetValue(a, null)
```

just change `a` to `content` like this :

```
var pairs = props.Select(x => x.Name + "=" + x.GetValue(content, null)).ToArray();
```

***content***  is name of your anonymous object .

But this solution you wrote not return dictionary . **if you want dictionary do this** :

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> convert(object content)
        {

            var props = content.GetType().GetProperties();
            var pairDictionary = props.ToDictionary(x => x.Name,x=>x.GetValue(content,null)?.ToString());
            return pairDictionary;
        }
```